# "I've missed you, too, darling" or "I've missed you too darling?"

Tags: commas

I'm having an argument with my girlfriend about which of these is correct. Could someone help? Commas necessary or no?

I don't consider this an exact duplicate question of "Happy Birthday, Sir!" because it also refers to the first comma. Should there be a first comma?

Comment: Also a duplicate of [Comma or no comma before “too”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/8109/191178).

Comment: "I've missed you too, darling." The first comma is unnecessary. But you need the second one, because of "you".

Comment: I'm wondering if the first comma is, in fact, necessary. As in, I think it might be (although I haven't seen nor used it myself in awhile)

Comment: Thanks @bread Any rule you could refer to here? Like, I'm pretty sure the first comma in the sentence "I, too, am happy." is correct. So I'm not sure what the difference is here?