# Should there be a comma before "though" when it occurs at the end of a sentence?

Tags: punctuation, adverbs, commas, sentence-ends

Consider

> I don't know how outdated it is though.

Should there be a comma before *though*, as in the following?

> I don't know how outdated it is, though.

---

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7093/comma-and-too

Answer (score 29, accepted):

*Though* is used as an adverb in this case, applied to the verb *is*, therefore no comma is strictly necessary.

Saying this, I can easily imagine a brief pauses between *is* and *though* when speaking the sentence, hence a *vocative comma* is acceptable.

In other words, take your pick. If I can avoid a comma (as in this case), I usually will. It's not wrong either way though.

Comment: (Oh dear, I think I subconsciously made a joke in the last sentence.)

Comment: I agree with this, though I have to note that I'm seeing more and more places where authors/editors seem to be cutting down on commas and omitting them where they're not strictly required for meaning. I'm doing the same in my own writing and feel it reads a little cleaner (though I still THINK the commas into place when reading).

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't surprise me too much. Commas can sometimes make sentences look more complicated than they are.

Comment: '_Though_ is used as an adverb in this case, applied to the verb _is_, therefore no comma is strictly necessary.' I think the comma is optional (and I prefer the pause it signals). I'd argue strongly against 'though _modifies_ be', and I note the use of the alternative '[is] applied to the verb _is_' here. But this is so far from central adverbial behaviour that I'd label _though_ here as a _pragmatic marker / pragmatic particle showing mild contrast or reserved judgement_. It's a discourse-detailing comment by the communicator, outside what the actual statement made in the matrix sentence is.

Comment: +1 I'd just like to add an anecdote - from personal experience, it would seem as though a "pre-though" comma is far more common in American English. I usually don't use one. However, "though" within sentences should be preceded by commas, e.g. *I am not American, though some of their grammatical rules interest me.* As an interesting aside, an end-of-sentence "however" is preceded by a comma, e.g. *American grammar can be interesting. I'm not American, however.*

Comment: @DogLover Yep, that sounds about right! Thanks for sharing. Do you use a pre- and post- comma when however is in the middle of a sentence? That's what I do.

Comment: (I suppose it depends exactly where "however" is placed within the syntactical structure, but it certainly has a pre- and post- comma at times, for me.)

Comment: @Noldorin Yes I do, except semicolon-comma, i.e. *I like semicolons; however, they can be hard to master.* I was actually taught the semicolon-comma before "however" rule by my Year 10 English teacher, and it has stuck with me since. Prior to that, I had used comma-comma. It irks me a bit when I only see a preceding comma.

Comment: @DogLover, +1 to that. I've seen both abundantly, but I prefer the semicolon-comma way, like you. I don't think I was taught it, mind you!

Answer (score 8):

I'd use the comma, but modern style would probably omit it.  There is a general tendency towards less punctuation.  Look at Victorian novels, and then compare with modern prose - there is much less punctuation now.  Or look at the King James Bible; that is rife with colons and semi-colons that would not appear nowadays, often not even 'demoted' to commas.  Punctuation style has changed over time.

Comment: Yup, but we do shorter sentences too. All Twitter's fault, of course :)

Answer (score 5):

I strongly prefer the second form, with the comma.

Say out loud, without a pause

> I don't know how outdated it is-though

Nonsense-speak to me.

Answer (score 1):

I believe both are correct. In general, you would use the comma if you would pause at that point if you spoke it aloud.